# Injecting class into controller - undefined variable

Tags: php, class, model-view-controller, laravel-4

I am trying to use a custom class in my controller. In the past I have use repositories and interfaces so Im not sure if what I am doing here is correct when not using those.

In my app directory I have a folder for my classes.

In there I have created a new folder called "ContactCentreSlideshow" then a class called "Slideshow.php"

This slideshow.php is simply:

```
namespace Classes\ContactCentreSlideshow;

class Slideshow {

  public function get_slideshow_interval()
  {
    return Constants::where('name', '=', 'slideshow_interval');
  }

}
```

My controller is then:

```
use Classes\ContactCentreSlideshow\Slideshow as Slideshow;

class ContactCentreSlideshowController extends BaseController {

protected $slideshow;

  public function __construct(Slideshow $slideshow)
  {
    $this->slideshow = $slideshow;
  }

  public function get_slideshow_interval()
  {
    return $slideshow->get_slideshow_interval();
  }

}
```

However I receive this error when calling the get_slideshow_interval method in the controller directly from a route.:

```
{"error":{"type":"ErrorException","message":"Undefined variable: slideshow","file":"\/Applications\/MAMP\/htdocs\/project\/app\/controllers\/ContactCentreSlideshowController.php","line":24}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When referencing member variables (i.e `$slideshow` in this case), you need to prefix it with `$this->`.

`get_slideshow_interval` should be:

```
public function get_slideshow_interval()
{
    return $this->slideshow->get_slideshow_interval();
}
```